# How to compute variance/confidence intervals from Fisher information matrix. Mistake in this document?

Tags: confidence-interval, fisher-information

https://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/5931/mle/mle.pdf

In this document (by the great Geyer nonetheless!)

it calculates confidence intervals using the Fisher matrix:

[image]

But the standard deviation is not the square-root of the element in the fisher matrix, you have to divide by $n$ first! Is this a huge mistake?

Comment: How does nlm compute Hessians?  is it possible that the factor is already absorbed into inv.fish?

Comment: Why would it do that? If I want to compute the hessian, surely it ought to give me the hessian, otherwise what's the point?

Comment: We need an expert in here!

Answer (score 5):

See section 1.4 about the confusion between $I_n(\theta)$ and $I_1(\theta)$.

You have $$Var (\hat\theta) \approx \frac{1}{I_n(\theta)} = \frac{1}{n I_1 (\theta)}$$